# Angular JS Sending an email from application

Tags: angularjs, email, amazon-s3

Hey I am hosting a Angular JS static website from an amazon s3 bucket with no web server, I am just wondering if I would like to send emails from this site what options do I have ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a zap: [how Zapier works](https://zapier.com/how-it-works/)

along with [AngularFire](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/), and an e-mail service like [Mandrill](https://mandrill.com/).

Your zap reacts to new entries in FireBase, and sends e-mail via Mandrill accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can integrate your JS app with [Mandrill](http://www.codecademy.com/courses/web-intermediate-en-hwulM/1/1), for example.